# Binning with python cut function gives wrong label to corresponding value

Tags: python, pandas

I have price data and I am trying to bin them in buckets as follows. I want to cut the price to `e.g. 2 -3, 4 - 5, 6 -7 and so on

```
s = pd.Series([1,4,45,70])
df =  pd.DataFrame(s, columns = ['price'])

labels = ["{0} - {1}".format(i, i + 1) for i in range(2, 70, 2)]
cut_bins = range(2, 71, 2)
```

However, when I look at the column created after binding I get the wrong bin's label assigned to the corresponding price in some cases.

```
df['price_bins'] = pd.cut(df['price'], bins= cut_bins,  labels=labels, include_lowest=True)

    price   price_bins
0   1        NaN
1   4      2 - 3
2   45     44 - 45
3   70     68 - 69
```

Can anyone advise/suggest what can I do to get the right, bins for the corresponding price tag

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `Nan`, then you can fix it like this:

Use `Series.cat.add_categories` for add categories first and replace the value of `Nan` with zero:

```
df['price_bins'] = pd.cut(df['price'], bins= cut_bins,  labels=labels, include_lowest=True).cat.add_categories(0).fillna(0)
df['price_bins']
```

And you need to replace `cut_bins = range(2, 71, 2)` with `cut_bins = range(0, 71, 2)`

Output:

```
0      2 - 3
1      4 - 5
2    46 - 47
3    70 - 71
Name: price_bins, dtype: category
Categories (36, object): ['2 - 3' < '4 - 5' < '6 - 7' < '8 - 9' ... '66 - 67' < '68 - 69' < '70 - 71' < 0]
```

Comment: its not about NAN, if you look bins for price  ` 4  is assigned to   bin  2 - 3  and   price 70   is assigned   68 - 69`

Comment: @user3459293 and what values should there be?

Comment: well, it should be like 4 should fall in 4 - 5 and 70 should fall in 70 - 72 bins

Comment: @user3459293 here is what you required

Comment: @user3459293 I have completed my answer

Comment: your solution does not solve the issue, i,m afraid !!

Comment: @user3459293 I added another solution option to my answer below the previous one, please take a look. And look at the output

Answer (score 0):

The issue is specifications of buckets and labels are incorrect.

Rather than want to cut the price to:

```
2 -3, 4 - 5, 6 -7 and so on
```

You need want to cut the price to:

```
2-3, 3-4, 4-5 and so on (where we take the left but not the right edge in each interval)
```

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1,4,45,70])
df =  pd.DataFrame(s, columns = ['price'])

r = range(2, 70)             # location of bucket breaks
cut_bins =  r                # using the bucket breaks points

# Generate labels i.e. 2-3, 3-4, 4-5 and so on
labels = ["{0} - {1}".format(start, stop) for start, stop in zip(r, r[1:])]

# Don't include the right most edge
df['price_bins'] = pd.cut(df['price'], bins= cut_bins,  labels=labels, right = False)  

print(df)
```

*Output*

```
   price price_bins
0      1        NaN
1      4      4 - 5
2     45    45 - 46
3     70        NaN
```